# DOM-based XSS - via URL

Tags: web-application, xss, javascript, dom

I have a website that I am testing but I am pretty new to all of this security stuff and would appreciate some help!.

I have a url similar to the following:

```
http://testurl?nexturl=whatever
```

The `nexturl` parameter determines what url should be displayed after something has happened.

I'm trying to test for XSS vulnerabilities and have disabled URL filtering in my browser. I am trying to replace the whatever with something like `<script>alert(1)</script>` and if I view the page source code I see "`nextUrl=<script>alert(1)</script>`" in it. However, I do not see an alert when the "something has happened".

Is there some better piece of javaScript I can put in to the URL to see if it is executed?

Comment: Does the page get redirected to `nexturl`? In that case, you can try `javascript:alert(1);`

Answer (score 1):

Since that's expecting a url (and not HTML tags), have you tried a javascript url?

```
javascript:alert(1)
```

---

Also, are you only testing for XSS, or would you also be interested in [open redirect](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards_Cheat_Sheet.html) issues?

Legitimate sites that a user trusts with arbitrary redirects like that are great for phishing attacks!

Consider that I get an email with a link:

```
https://yoursite.com/account?nexturl=https://evilsite.com/passwordcollector
```

I use `yoursite.com`, I'm happy to log in and view my account! Then after interacting with it, it takes me back to the login page. Weird, I though I'd already logged in, oh well, guess I'll log in again ...

Comment: Thanks so much! I've just realised that the nexturl gets stored in a cookie. Is this still a vulnerabilty? How could an attacker exploit this?

Comment: Hmm. I can't think off the top of my head how putting it in a cookie would be a problem; it depends what the server does with that cookie.